# Nexus 5 freezing often

Tags: nexus-5, lg

I have a new Nexus 5. Ever since I got it, it tends to freeze. Once or twice a day, I would pick it up, try to press something and see that the screen is completely nonresponsive. The only thing I can do is press the power button for 8 seconds until it resets.

Why is this? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this?

It's faulty.

> What can I do about it?

Return it to the vendor for repair or replacement. Nobody should expect this kind of problem with a new phone. It's not on you to fix it.

Comment: I've rooted my phone... Doesn't that void the warranty?

Comment: I don't know what kind of consumer protection laws you have in Israel, but in the UK, as it's a new phone and the problem was present when you bought it, that makes it the retailer's responsibility. The warranty is irrelevant in that case.